# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in .NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Here is my code:

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AppCORSPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
    
    ...

    app.UseCors("AppCORSPolicy");
```

It seems to work fine if my client is on the same host as the api. However when I move the client to different host the problem persists.

I get the following error in the browser:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com' from origin 'http://localhost:4200'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

I checked to make sure that I have things loading in the correct order per the documentation. Can't seem to get past this error.

Comment: What are the headers being returned by `OPTION [endpoint]`? We need more info.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary The only response headers that are returned are contact-type, date, set-cookie (during the OPTIONS Method). Then the real http call gets blocked by the browser with that error message.

Answer (score 0):

The order of UseCors and UseHttpsRedirection should be the same as the code below. And it works for me in my side.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

  ...
  app.UseCors("AppCORSPolicy");

  app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 
  ...
 }
```

And I also found a good blog about [Setup a Proxy for API Calls for Your Angular CLI App](https://betterprogramming.pub/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d).

If the above method has not solved this problem, you can refer to the content in the link below.